# Tab to select autocomplete item in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, configuration, autocomplete, intellisense, preferences

I can't find either the term **autocomplete** or **intellisense** in Preferences->General->Keys in Eclipse 3.6.2.

I don't want to press enter to select an autocomplete item when I write code. Can I configure Eclipse to accept an autocomplete item with the *tab button*?

Comment: CTRL+SPACE usually does that. Search where this shortcut is used in the Preferences.

Comment: I had the same problem, especially when using php in eclipse. After typing ", eclipse will automatically makes it "". After typing some information inside "", I want to jump to the right side of " by using Tab - not right arrow button. This has been done well in Java, but not PHP (PDT plugin) in eclipse :(

Comment: Try filtering with "assist" as this feature is called "Content Assist" in Eclipse.

Comment: And the short answer is that I don't think there is a configurable setting for that unfortunately, at least not one that I could find under OSX/Helios.

Comment: @tsubasa I believe that in that case you can just type `"` again and it will move your cursor to the right of the pre-existing closing `"`.

Comment: @nicolas, now the situation is something like this:
define("Hello","Hello World!"); do I have to type " then ) in the Hello World ? I wish I just need to press Tab button...

Comment: @karlphillip - 'Ctrl + Space' does it by default, but is horrendously inconvenient compared to just using the tab key.  You can use the preferences section to remap content-assist to the tab key, but then you lose the ability to have tabs in your code.  This is a serious and long-standing shortcoming in Eclipse, in my opinion.

Comment: CTRL + SPACE is not the default key combination for this -- CTRL + SPACE *OPENS* the menu, it does not commit the auto complete.  Reassigning "Content Assist" to another key combination, you'll see that this is the case.

Comment: It seems you can do this by reassigning the keys for "ALT+/" to TAB (this is Word completion) -- but you can't do it from the editor -- you have to export your preferences edit the text file and then reimport. -- Doing this works great, but it disables the ability to use TAB for other purposes (like tabbing!!), so it's probably not what you want. :-(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just got it, go to Window>Preferences>General->Keys and look for "Word completion" as said before. Then near the bottom is "Binding" and to the right of it, a box with an arrow, clicking there you can select "Tab" to use Tabulator for autocomplete.

Comment: Beware, if you set the Tab key to "Word Completion", it might be possible that you lose the ability to insert tab characters when typing your source codes.

Comment: @tom_mai78101 This is stupid... All other IDE's and programming text editors I have used use tab to insert the selected item in the auto-completion list. If someone prefers Enter for that, that is fine, but there should have been some easy setting to change it to tab without this kind of pitfall.

Comment: shift+Tab is little better.

Comment: For some reason, I have to download the newest version of Eclipse (namely the `2023‑06` version), and the above method does not work anymore. In specific, instead of selecting the autocomplete proposal, it will just change itself into another word. A great example is `in` to `inReader` proposed by `Java Proposal`; it will change into unreasoned words like `incoming`, etc.

Answer (score 13):

I believe you are looking for "word completion" Left Alt + / though you can change it in "Preferences->General->Keys" to be whatever key combo. Pressing / multiple times cycles through the different suggestions. It's not very intelligent. For example if you have `String apple;` and `double apps;` and you type `double x = a` and then Alt + / eclipse might suggest apple instead of apps, even though apple is an String.

Edit: Looks like it's ctrl + / on some computers.

Answer (score 2):

The autocompletion selection key(s) is editor specific. For instance in Aptana Studio, you could define set of keys for proposal selection. See e.g. Preferences/Aptana Studio/Editors/JavaScript. PyDev shares some code with Aptana Studio, so it has similar capabilities. See "Preferences/PyDev/Editor/Code Completion/Apply completion on *" checkboxes.

Speaking of the Tab key as a selector, it doesn't seem possible w/o extra coding since it has special meaning to focus into proposals window. For these who interested could find Tab handling at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup.verifyKey(VerifyEvent)

Cheers,
Max

Comment: Isn't the hotkey for focusing into proposals window, `F2`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the same question is asked here [Change hotkey for autocomplete selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663015/change-hotkey-for-autocomplete-selection)

> All key bindings in Eclipse are defined in Window -> Preferences ->
>   General -> Keys. I don't think you can change what is used to select
>   stuff from the autocomplete list, but you can use space to select and
>   then Enter for new line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this trick as mentioned -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/6508181/474002

After you jump to the item you want, press `Tab` -> `Space`

It's done. Hope this will help :)